# How to list monospace (fixed-width) fonts in WPF

Tags: wpf, fonts

I need to add font chooser to my WPF text editor. I'm adapting [this font chooser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2006/11/01/sample-font-chooser.aspx).

However, it lists all the installed fonts. I only need a list of fixed-width (monospace) fonts.

How do I check if a given System.Windows.Media.FontFamily is a fixed-width font?

There is a solution [that uses System.Drawing.FontFamily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224865/how-do-i-get-all-installed-fixed-width-fonts) but those fonts are not exactly compatible with WPF and the code I'm adapting uses System.Windows.Media.FontFamily.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can filter the System.Windows.Media.FontFamily list by creating a System.Drawing.Font with the same name and use inteop and LOGFONT from there.

This is a horrible hack but I believe it will work in most cases (if you only use fonts installed on the system the System.Windows.Media.FontFamily and System.Drawing.FontFamily lists should mostly match)

Using something like this to get font sizing information or information about advanced font properties would be completely useless due to the differences in the font renderer between WPF and GDI - but for basic properties of the font like being fixed-width I expect this should work.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about getting a list of names of fixed-width fonts as a filter, either the way you propose or pinvoke'ing directly to EnumFonts(), but I was hoping there is a less hacky way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var monoSpacedFonts = Fonts.SystemFontFamilies
            .Where(f => f.IsMonoSpace());
```

---

A bit *janky* and not thoroughly tested but seems to work using the following Extension Methods:

---

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace StackOverflow;

internal static class ExtensionMethods {

    internal static bool IsMonoSpace(this FontFamily @this) {
        var result = true;
        double? widthComparison = null;
        foreach (var typeface in @this.GetTypefaces()) {

            foreach (var sample in new char[] { '!', 'W' }) {
                var actualWidth = sample.DerivedWidth(typeface);
                widthComparison = widthComparison ?? actualWidth;
                if (widthComparison != actualWidth) {
                    result = false;
                    goto Discontinue;
                }

            }
        }
    Discontinue:
        return result;
    }

    internal static double DerivedWidth(this char @this, Typeface typeface, double emSize = 16.0d)
        => new FormattedText(
            @this.ToString(),
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            typeface,
            emSize,
            Brushes.Black
            ).Width;

}
```