# Determining if VB.NET font is fixed-width

Tags: vb.net, fonts

I would like to iterate through a long **array of fonts** and **determine** their statuses as **fixed/non-fixed width** and **textual/symbolic** fonts.

Is it possible, given an arbitrary font, to determine whether or not it is fixed-width or variable-width?  It certainly does not seem to be a simple, single variable - some measurements probably need to be done.  However, I would like to avoid having iconic or symbolic fonts register as such, which there also may not necessarily be a property for.

Comment: check this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224865/how-do-i-get-all-installed-fixed-width-fonts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224865/how-do-i-get-all-installed-fixed-width-fonts)

Comment: @GuidoPreite  A very similar question and a decent answer, but I don't think it answers my question completely.  What about symbolic fonts?  And can I really trust this "tologfont"?

Comment: Tim's answer to the linked question is correct. Yes, of course you can trust `ToLogFont`. It returns a Win32 [`LOGFONT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145037.aspx) structure that describes the underlying font. Symbolic fonts carry metadata, too, so this will work fine for them. Measuring it yourself is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @CodyGray Is there a property in this structure than is able to distinguish symbolic, wing-ding, or otherwise standard textual fonts?

Comment: The `FF_DECORATIVE` flag should be set for symbolic fonts like Wingdings. Check it like so: `If (logfont.lfPitchAndFamily And FF_DECORATIVE) = FF_DECORATIVE Then`

Comment: @CodyGray Excellent!  This would make a great answer, I feel.

Comment: I was aiming to close the question as a duplicate of the linked one, that's why I didn't post an answer. I cast a vote myself, but this one is pretty old, it's probably not getting enough traffic to accumulate enough additional votes.

Comment: @CodyGray Alright... well feel free to answer it, then.  Your additional information about symbolic fonts is what makes my question differ from the other, is what I need, and is what you are providing.  So I see no issue.